# InvalidMagicIdException: Not able to add cache in infinispan

Tags: apache-nifi, infinispan

I am working on infinispan... But while adding cache to it with rest

`POST /rest/v2/caches/{cacheName}/{cacheKey}` and with nifi also, but it gives me a following error

```
12:17:55,695 ERROR [org.infinispan.server.hotrod.BaseRequestProcessor] (HotRod-ServerIO-5-1) ISPN005003: Exception reported: org.infinispan.server.hotrod.InvalidMagicIdException: Error reading magic byte or message id: 10
at org.infinispan.server.hotrod:ispn-10.0@10.0.0.Beta3//org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodDecoder.switch0(HotRodDecoder.java:208)
at org.infinispan.server.hotrod:ispn-10.0@10.0.0.Beta3//org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodDecoder.switch1_0(HotRodDecoder.java:153)
at org.infinispan.server.hotrod:ispn-10.0@10.0.0.Beta3//org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodDecoder.decode(HotRodDecoder.java:143)
at io.netty:ispn-10.0@4.1.30.Final//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
at io.netty:ispn-10.0@4.1.30.Final//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
at io.netty:ispn-10.0@4.1.30.Final//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
```

I am using `docker pull jboss/infinispan-server`  `10.0.0.beta` and `10.0.0.CR1-3`.

I ma not getting any clue to trace the issue.

Comment: Stack trace shows that the server thinks that you're using Hot Rod protocol while you use REST. So either you have different ports configured for those and you're reaching the wrong one, or you use single port for both protocols and for some reason the server could not decide correctly where you want to go.

Comment: could you please try the jboss/infinispan-server:10.1.1.Final-3 ?